# Wordpress. Woocommerce. Action hook BEFORE adding to cart

Tags: wordpress, hook, woocommerce

**What i need to do:**
I want to run some checks on a product before being added to the cart.
*More exactly:*
I want to compare the product i am about to add to the cart, with the ones already added, to see if there are some conflicts. 
*An example:*
Let's say we have a product named "Both shoes", and a product "left shoe".
A user adds "left shoe" to the cart. Then he adds "both shoes". I want to print an error instead of adding the "both shoes": Sorry, but you can't add both shoes if you've added left shoe to the cart. If you want to buy "both shoes", please first remove "left shoe".

I've looked at class-wc-cart.php and i found an action hook at line **811**, **but it's too late! It's after the product has been added**

"do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );"

The add_to_cart method starts at line **705**.
http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#705

How can my "product conflict manager" function be hooked before line 801, **without hacking woocommerce?**

Thank you!

Comment: If i were to hack it, i would just add the following lines at line 799:

`if(!do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ))
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }`

And use `add_action ('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart','add_to_cart_conflict_manage',10,6);` in my functions.php

Comment: ^ or something similar to that

Comment: The hack ended being actually a filter instead of an action

`// This is supposed to handle product conflicts and check if user already has access to the product //
$product_conflict_error = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data,$product_data);
if (product_conflict_error)
{
$woocommerce->add_error( __($product_conflict_error, 'woocommerce') );
return false;
}`

Comment: Have you discovered an answer to this problem? I am having the same issue and haven't had any luck finding the correct hook.

Answer (score 41):

A bit late, but I think you are looking for add to cart validation, which is filterable. Here's an over simplified version:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {

    // do your validation, if not met switch $passed to false
    if ( 1 != 2 ){
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Thanks! ^_^ This totally put me on the right path; however, I noticed an erroneous closing bracket on the `add_filter` line, and it needs the number of arguments for the filter set along with the priority (`add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5);`), otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: How can we make it work when the products are added via ajax?

Comment: Validation is run even when a product is added via ajax.