# How to disable ADD TO CARTs by bots in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce website

Some bots are doing ATC on my products which I want to stop

I have GET links behind ADD TO CART buttons on `/product-category/*` and `/product-tag/*` pages and I removed them, changed to to POST so clicking ADD TO CART makes POST request to `/?wc-ajax=add_to_cart` instead

But somehow bots are doing GET requests on pages like these

```
/product-tag/my-product/page/237?add-to-cart=30323
/product-category/games/page/5/?add-to-cart=282290
```

I dont know where are they getting links from

I can see requests coming from Petalbot and also from random bot

1. How can I stop `add-to-cart` using GET request completely?
2. Whats best `robots.txt` for a Wocommerce website

this is current `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Sitemap: https://website.com/wp-sitemap.xml
```

I am more interested in solution of 1, because just disallowing add-to-cart URLs wont stop those bad bots from doing ATC because they don't obey `robots.txt` at all.

Comment: If you are the hacker who wrote the bot, do you think you will obey robots.txt ? There is also no point to attempt changing from GET to POST or vice versa because the hacker can easily switch to either one by using the right commands in say `curl`. Better stop them thru firewall (e.g. check the access_log and find the bad IPs and block them).  There may also be plugins (free or paid) to do similar things so you may search for WP plugins which do the job.

Comment: you recaptcha, hcaptcha etc.

Comment: Add an extra level with session tokens.

Comment: I wanted to disable `add-to-cart` completely via GET requests because when a real user clicks on ATC its a POST request anyways

Comment: to the people who closed question for not being "programming related", can you tell me how this is not "programming related"? I have been using SO for years and been a SE myself for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to totally disable add to cart via GET requests, this should work:

```php
function prevent_get_request_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {

    if (isset($_GET['add-to-cart'])) {
        // show error if you want
        // wc_add_notice('GET requests for add to cart is not allowed.', 'error');

        return false;
    }

    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'prevent_get_request_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

I didn't test it myself, but it should work, It prevent item from being add to cart if `add-to-cart` GET parameter exists.

I got help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22751573/6934036)